# How to type characters in Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass

In my Glass application, I have created a preference fragment for users to enter some important information such as name, password, etc. When run, the preference item does come up as expected. However, I couldn't find a way to key in the characters. Is there a soft keyboard or some other way to enter text in an edit control in Glass? Or, is there a replacement for preferences UI in Glass that will let me key in characters? Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using a Bluetooth keyboard, no, there isn't any way to do this.

In general, you will probably want to minimize how much configuration is done through Glass itself. Although https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication is listed as being used for authentication, it can also be used to store user preferences, and you may find this a much better way to provide a UI.